# Tag merge / Synonym request: [programming-languages] --> [languages]

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

- [programming-languages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages) - 774 questions
- [languages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages) - 52 questions

**They're the same thing people!** At least in the sense that we use it (seeing that we have a [spoken-languages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoken-languages) tag), they are used the same way.

Can we merge it all into one big [languages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages) tag? Or maybe into the [programming-languages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages) tag?

Comment: It seems that some [languages] questions are about [spoken-languages], for example: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/113936/is-it-a-good-practice-to-code-in-english, and they should be retagged as [spoken-languages] before we merge the tag with [programming-languages].

Comment: @YannisRizos I didn't notice that. I'll go through them now.

Comment: @YannisRizos I'll finish going through them later. Don't want to spam the front page.

Comment: Prior art: [Tag Merge Discussion: languages, programming-languages](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2081/tag-merge-discussion-languages-programming-languages), notably Jeff's answer. Also see [Let's nuke the catch-all tags](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2373/lets-nuke-the-catch-all-tags): [tag:programming-languages] is a crap tag that isn't used correctly at all.

Comment: @MarkTrapp So you are saying that [programming-languages] itself should just be nuked?

Comment: @Dynamic Indeed.

Comment: @MarkTrapp But the [languages] tag shouldn't?

Comment: @Dynamic Given it's used exactly the same as [tag:programming-languages], I don't see why it should exist either. If, after almost 2 years, it hasn't been used in a way that conveys semantic information, no sense in keeping it around based on some theoretical value.

Comment: @MarkTrapp So I guess this post was pointless. It would involve another cleanup to get rid of a tag that big...

Comment: @MarkTrapp A cleanup of that size would be bigger than the [career] cleanup.

Comment: @Dynamic [tag:career] and [tag:programming-languages] do not share the same problems: [tag:career] needed to be split up and disambiguated because—while it was a bad tag—it contained some semantic information that would be lost if we just removed it completely. [tag:programming-languages], on the other hand, tells us *nothing* about the nature of the question: *every* question here could be tagged with it. It can just be completely removed: we did it with [tag:best-practices] and it took SE about 5 minutes to do.

Comment: The only major difficulty—assuming there's consensus to blast the tag—will be that, because [tag:programming-languages] has been synonymous with "I don't want to think about tagging", there's probably going to be a large number of untagged questions once it's nuked. But that's a much easier problem to deal with than having to do a [meta-tag:STCI] event like we did with [tag:career].

Comment: @YannisRizos All finished retagging :-)